# Rails: "is not a module" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model, namespaces

I am using namespaces and folders to group my models in Rails and am running into an issue whereby the file is not loaded and a `TypeError - is not a module` error is being thrown.

Here is top of the trace:

```
17:06:26 web.1  | TypeError - SetNetsuite is not a module:
17:06:26 web.1  |   app/models/integrations/set_netsuite/scenarios/new_mavenlink_project.rb:2:in `<module:Integrations>'
17:06:26 web.1  |   app/models/integrations/set_netsuite/scenarios/new_mavenlink_project.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
17:06:26 web.1  |   activesupport (4.1.10) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `block in load_file'
17:06:26 web.1  |   activesupport (4.1.10) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:633:in `new_constants_in'
17:06:26 web.1  |   activesupport (4.1.10) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:442:in `load_file'
17:06:26 web.1  |   activesupport (4.1.10) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `require_or_load'
17:06:26 web.1  |   activesupport (4.1.10) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:480:in `load_missing_constant'
17:06:26 web.1  |   activesupport (4.1.10) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:180:in `const_missing'
17:06:26 web.1  |   activesupport (4.1.10) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:240:in `block in constantize'
17:06:26 web.1  |   activesupport (4.1.10) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `constantize'
17:06:26 web.1  |   activesupport (4.1.10) lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `constantize'
```

My code looks like this:

```
module Integrations
  module SetNetsuite
    module Scenarios
      class NewProject < Scenario
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And my folder structure is:

```
- models/
  - integrations/
    - set_netsuite/
      - scenarios/
        - new_project.rb
```

I am autoloading everything in `/models`:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '{**}')]
```

If I change the model to this, it works:

```
module Integrations
  class SetNetsuite::Scenarios::NewProject < Scenario
  end
end
```

I know that namespaced classes behave slightly differently to nested modules, but I would rather go with the nested module approach.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: the `end` is missing for Integrations module

Comment: whoops thanks for that. Unfortunately that was just a mis-type in my question writeup. The 'missing' end is present in the code.

Comment: did you already have defined an `SetNetsuite` class in other place?

Comment: No I haven't defined that class elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

### UPD

It seems you `require 'integrations'` and all the rest modules in `new_mavenlink_project.rb`, while you shouldn't, whole point of autoloading is you don't need to require anything anywhere in rails application. To access your NewProject class you should simply call:

```
Integrations::SetNetsuite::Scenarios::NewProject
```

And in this case you won't need to add anything to `autoload_paths`, rails will generate it from the nesting.